# SQL Server: return last day of the last year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Take a look at this code portion.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX), @DateWithDotsVARCHAR(10)

SELECT @DateWithDots = REPLACE(@Date, '-', '.')

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##WL_Klijenti') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE ##WL_Klijenti

SELECT @SQL = '
    SELECT * 
     INTO ##WL_Klijenti
      FROM  OPENROWSET (''SQLOLEDB'',''Server=
     (local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;'',''SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    EXEC 
   '+DB_NAME()+'.dbo.sp_kbbl_WachLista_Priprema ''''' + @DateWithDots+ 
 ''''', ''''' + @DateWithDots + ''''', 0'')
AS tbl'
... the rest is less important
```

> [Second dateWithDots](http://oi66.tinypic.com/dh4b9l.jpg) is not needed as user input but here I will have to pass the
>   **last day of the last year** instead, in reference to the first @dateWithDots user will input.
>   (This is due to some balance sheet calculations, everything works fine here I just have to set this adjustment.)

So somehow I will have to identify the current year beforehand, `YEAR` can be taken from the first `@DateWithDots` as this is requested user input parameter.

How can it be accomplished ?

---

**SOLUTIONS:**

@Cool_Br33ze's approach...

```
DECLARE @dateWithDots NVARCHAR(10)
SET @dateWithDots = '2018.01.18' --<< User Inputted date
SELECT LastDayLastYear = CAST(DATEADD(YEAR, 
            DATEDIFF(YEAR, -1, CAST(@dateWithDots AS DATE) )-1, -1) AS DATE)
```

My approach...

```
DECLARE @LastDay VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @LastDay = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),SUBSTRING(@Datum,1,4)-1) + '.12' + '.31';
```

Comment: First, you don't need dynamic SQL. Second, it would be a LOT easier if you created a linked server. As it is, the query is almost unreadable. Finally, what does all this have to do with retrieving December 31 of the previous year? Just get the Year part of GETDATE() and subtract one.

Comment: Use the correct datatypes for Dates like `DATE` or `DATETIME` not `VARCHAR`

Comment: This is all part of one procedure, everything is fine, there is no need to change anything here except I have to pass second date as last day of last year, some balance calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE the correct the Datatypes for Dates

```
DECLARE @dateWithDots DATE
SET @dateWithDots = GETDATE()  --<< User Inputted date

SELECT LastDayLastYear = CAST(DATEADD(YEAR, 
            DATEDIFF(YEAR, -1, @dateWithDots )-1, -1) AS DATE)
```

Returns

> 2017-12-31

Using `NVARCHAR` for Dates

```
DECLARE @dateWithDots NVARCHAR(10)
SET @dateWithDots = '2018.01.18' --<< User Inputted date
SELECT LastDayLastYear = CAST(DATEADD(YEAR, 
                DATEDIFF(YEAR, -1, CAST(@dateWithDots AS DATE) )-1, -1) AS DATE)
```

Returns

> 2017-12-31

--Using Dynamic SQL - NVARCHAR is preferred over VARCHAR

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) ;
SET @SQL = N'SELECT CAST(DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR, -1, CAST(@dateWithDots AS DATE) )-1, -1) AS DATE)'
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@dateWithDots NVARCHAR(10)', @dateWithDots
```

Comment: This shall do the work, thank you.
How can I pass this to my select @SQL statement?
It has to be executed within it.

Comment: And one more thing, I need to return last day of the last year relevant to the @dateWithDots user will input.
How can I extract year from the user input?

Comment: Something like this:
SET @ lastDay = YEAR(@DatumSaTackama);
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, -1, @ lastDay )-1, -1);

And now, how can I pass it to @Sql statement ?

Comment: @T_Dejan I've included a Dynamic SQL example